# how to create a queue in c#.net?

Tags: c#, .net

the kind of program that i actually want to write is:there are different data that comes in from a server and we have to send that data to another server,and among that data we have to filter data,make some internal calculation from our side and then we have to send,for that my idea is to create a queue ,where data can reside for a fixed time..we will do internal calculation and send and at that time other data that are coming will reside in another queue..and after the first queue is executed ,then we can do internal calculation for another queue but cant get idea ,about how to implement queue in c#.net?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx) class yet? It's a good idea to say what you've already tried.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the:

- [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx)
- [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx)
- [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx)

classes?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a queues distributed across machines, you can go with Microsoft Message Queue (MSMQ) or even better a Bus architecture ([NServiceBus](http://nservicebus.com), [Rhino Service Bus](http://ayende.com/blog/3752/rhino-service-bus), [MassTransit](http://code.google.com/p/masstransit/)) to have that kind of distributed processing.

Answer (score 1):

There are many alternatives

[.NET Queue class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx)

[Blocking Collection in .NET 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx)

[Blocking Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163427.aspx#S4) by joe duffy

[Producer consumer queue](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Wait_Pulse_Producer_Consumer_Queue) by Joe Albahari